# Clarification for theorem 55.5 in Munkres topology

Tags: general-topology

The theorem 55.5 in Munkres says that,
given a non vanishing vector field on $B^2$, there exits a point of $S^1$ where the vector field points directly inward.
What is the precise meaning of "the vector field points directly inward"?

Comment: It means the vector field at that point on $S^1$ points directly at the origin.

Comment: @RobertShore Let $v$ be the vector field, so that v(x) = -x, is this what you mean?

Comment: @Andy not quite it means if $v$ is the vector field, $v(x) = \alpha x$ where $\alpha < 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that for some $x \in S^1$ we have $v(x) = \alpha x$ for some $\alpha <0$ (directly outwards would be $\alpha>0$). The vector field "vanishes" at $x$ if $v(x)=0$, etc.